# Why do I get 'Input Assembler: "No mesh available for stage"' error?

Tags: directx11, visual-studio

My question is basically why VS2012 tells me that there is no mesh available for the Input Assembler stage because if I click on the DeviceContext next to the Draw call in the Grahics Event List the Input layout is set correctly, the vertex buffers, too, the index buffer is `NULL` as I do not call DrawIndexed and the primitive topology is set correctly. My background color is drawn using `g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, Colors::MidnightBlue );`. Only the mesh does not appear. What did I miss?

If anything maybe this file which can be opened using VS2012 may help, it is the <s>Graphics Experiment.vsglog file</s> <sup>(*link no longer available*)</sup>.

Here is my InputLayout struct:

```
struct VERTEXPOSITIONCOLOR
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3   position;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4   color;

    static D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC* GetVertexLayout()
    {
        static D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
        {
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,
                0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,
                0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        };
        return layout;
    }

    static UINT GetNumElements(){ return 2; }
};
```

Comment: Have you called `IASetVertexBuffers` on your vertex buffer prior to the draw call.

Comment: Yes, I have. (Just checked again). And as I mentioned above the vertex buffers are set correctly in the debugging window. It would be `NULL` like the IndexBuffer if I had not called `IASetVertexBuffers`.

Comment: In the graphics pipeline in VS can you see the mesh in the input assembler stage?

Comment: No. Only the text "No mesh avaiable for stage" is displayed.

Comment: Have you enabled the D3D debug layer?  Any interesting warning messages showing up?

Comment: No warning messages except that a registry value is too long, but that always appears, even with working examples.

Comment: Just looked at your vslog, are you trying to draw a single triangle?

Comment: That is correct :).

Comment: Please post your input layout struct, I don't think it is correct.

Comment: Ok, that looks fine. What's your draw call look like?

Comment: You mean this? `pd3dImmediateContext->Draw( vertexStart, vertexCount );` with `vertexStart=0` and `vertexCount=3` according to the VS2012 Debugger.

Comment: Yeah you have that backwards, count first, start index second.

Comment: Please add as an answer. So that I can check it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your (no longer available) vslog it would appear you have the first and second parameter in your draw call mixed up as it says `Draw(0, 3)`.

The first parameter is the vertex count and the second parameter is the start offset. See the [documentation about ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476407(v=vs.85).aspx).